# Непонятки с функцией connect и accept

Tags: c, сеть

Ребят, у меня тут назрело два вопроса:

---

1. Функция `connect` (`int connect(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *serv_addr, int addrlen);`) принимает во второй аргумент адрес сервера, тогда зачем мне указывать какое семейство адресов у сокета этого сервера в приложении клиенте (`addr.sin_family=AF_INET;`)? Почему нельзя просто айпишник и порт указать?

---

2. В строке `socket2=accept(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&client,(socklen_t*)&len_client);` во втором аргументе указана структура, в которую записывается адрес сокета клиента. Вопрос, откуда он берет этот адрес? Я же не передаю его никак в функцию `connect`.

Comment: `accept()` срабатывает на стороне сервера *в ответ* на `connect()` у клиента. **ОС на стороне сервера** записывает во второй аргумент `accept()` **адрес клиента**

Comment: @avp, спасибо))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> зачем мне указывать какое семейство адресов у сокета этого
>   сервера(addr.sin_family=AF_INET;)? Почему нельзя просто айпишник и
>   порт указать?

Потому, что один и тот же порт, зачастую, может работать как с UDP, так и с TCP. Например:

25 порт - SMTP: UDP/TCP Может принимать пакеты на UDP  порт и соединения на TCP порт.

> откуда он берет этот адрес?

Согласно "RFC 791 — Протокол IP"  в заголовке **любого** пакета IP должны присутствовать как адрес получателя (т.е. алрес Вашего сервера) так и адрес **отправителя** - клиента, пытающегося работать с Вашим сервером.

Comment: Так TCP и UDP имеют одинаковое семейство адресов - AF_INET

Comment: Но есть и другие семейства сокетов.  На том же самом хосте.

Comment: ааа, спасибо, сейчас все стало очень понятно. Если бы я смог выбрать два правильных ответа, я бы выбрал. Но ваш ответ вместе с вашим комментарием мне более понятен, поэтому поставлю галочку у вас)

Comment: Различие между TCP и UDP на самом деле берется **не из addr.sin_family** (в обоих случаях для IPv4 там д.б. **AF_INET**), а из типа сокета (**второй аргумент** вызова socket(domain, type, protocol); **SOCK_STREAM -- tcp, SOC_DGRAM -- udp**) / Одни и те же номера портов в TCP и UDP это в реальности совсем разные порты, поэтому фраза `"один и тот же порт, зачастую, может работать как с UDP, так и с TCP"` вводит в заблуждение

Comment: @name на самом деле, они запросто могут иметь и AF_INET6, и AF_UNSPEC

Answer (score 4):

Интересный вопрос (особенно первая часть -- `"...зачем мне указывать какое семейство адресов у сокета этого сервера?"`, побудившая меня перечитать manpages)

В самом деле, если мы посмотрим на вызов [socket()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), то увидим, что в аргументе `domain` задаются те же константы (`AF_INET` и т.п.), что и в поле `sockadr.sin_family` в вызове [connect()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html). На первый взгляд кажется, что и в самом деле это поле избыточно при вызове `connect()`.

Однако, оно используется по крайней мере для достижения двух целей.

Во-первых, это проверка целостности (не противоречивости) данных. При вызове `connect()` происходит проверка, что семейство адресов, задаваемое в поле `.sin_family` адреса сервера соответствует допустимым протоколам сокета ([address_families](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/address_families.7.html)), которые были заданы в аргументе `domain` при его создании.

А второй возможный ответ кроется вот в этом абзаце из `man connect`:

> Generally,  connection-based  protocol sockets may successfully
>   connect()
>          only once; connectionless protocol sockets  may  use  connect()  multiple
>          times  to  change their association.  Connectionless sockets may dissolve
>          the association by connecting to an address with the sa_family member  of
>          sockaddr set to AF_UNSPEC (supported on Linux since kernel 2.2).

более конкретно, в словах: *"`Connectionless sockets may dissolve the association...`*`...`**`with the sa_family member of sockaddr set to AF_UNSPEC`**`"`

Т.е. для сокетов типа `SOCK_STREAM` (а именно с ними мы в основном используем `connect`) поле `.sin_family` (если отбросить проверки непротиворечивости) избыточно, но оно нужно (очевидно, не часто) для использования `connect` с `SOCK_DGRAM` сокетами (обычно мы вообще не используем `connect()`, работая с ними, а задаем адрес получателя непосредственно в вызове [sendto](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendto.2.html)).

---

Что касается второй части вопроса об адресе клиента в серверном вызове `accept()` --`"откуда он берет этот адрес? Я же не передаю его никак в функцию connect"`, то ответ следующий:

`accept()` срабатывает на стороне сервера **в ответ на** `connect()` у клиента. **ОС на стороне сервера** записывает во второй аргумент accept() адрес клиента.

Само значение своего адреса клиент либо задает сам, вызывая [bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) перед вызовом `connect()`, либо (если `bind()` не использовали) оно формируется ОС в ходе вызова `connect()` из первичного адреса сетевого интерфейса, который алгоритмы роутинга выбирают для данного соединения и свободного динамического номера порта (см. [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82) (обычно где-то от 65535 до 49000)).

Далее этот адрес передается во всех IP-пакетах (включая первый пакет с запросом соединения), которыми обмениваются клиент с сервером.